# Enterprise Library Section Error

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library

Everytime when I open my Solution that is using the Enterprise Library from Microsoft I get this error after building or opening my app.config.

[image]

After this Message my Visual Studio is shutting down ! My Configuration hasn't changed for a year and I only got this error just since a few days. I don't know where it comes from and why VS is shutting down after this Message ...

Anyone knows this error maybe ?

My Config looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="enterpriselibrary.configurationSettings" type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=....." />
</configSections>
<enterpriselibrary.configurationSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" applicationName="...." xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/practices/enterpriselibrary/08-31-2004/configuration">
  <configurationSections>
    <configurationSection xsi:type="ReadOnlyConfigurationSectionData" name="dataConfiguration" encrypt="true">
      <storageProvider xsi:type="XmlFileStorageProviderData" name="XML File Storage Provider" path="......" />
      <dataTransformer xsi:type="XmlSerializerTransformerData" name="Xml Serializer Transformer">
        <includeTypes />
      </dataTransformer>
    </configurationSection>
  </configurationSections>
  <keyAlgorithmStorageProvider xsi:type="FileKeyAlgorithmPairStorageProviderData" name="File Key Algorithm Storage Provider" path="....">
    <dpapiSettings xsi:nil="true" />
  </keyAlgorithmStorageProvider>
  <includeTypes />
</enterpriselibrary.configurationSettings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting the configsections into the machine.config solved the problem. Unfortunately I don't understand the reason ...